# Printing real data type from sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, type-conversion

I have real data type values in my database. But when i try print (php) i can see very long numbers:

```
512.2   501.12  506.66 in db

$variable = $row['column_name'];
```

then i receive values like: 
512.20001220703 and 
501.11999511719

how to parse in to normal format?

Comment: `sprintf('%.2f', $variable)` ; http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$variable = round($row['column_name'],2); //display 2 decimal
```

Comment: While this code may help answer the question, code only answers are not high quality. A better answer would explain what the code does, tell where to insert it, explain why this approach was taken, and link to relevant documentation.